# No response from OpenAi using Flask

Tags: python-3.x, api, flask, openai-api

I'm trying to built a chat bot using opeanAI. I have no idea why I can not see the response when using the following python code :

```
import openai
import streamlit as st

from flask import Flask, request, render_template
import openai

app = Flask(__name__)

# Set the GPT-3 API key
openai.api_key = st.secrets["Key"]

# Define the routes for the Flask app
@app.route('/')
def index():
    # Feature detection
    is_fetch_supported = True
    if not hasattr(request, 'user_agent') or not request.user_agent.browser or request.user_agent.browser.family != 'Firefox':
        try:
            fetch = window.fetch
            fetch('https://example.com', { method: 'HEAD' })
        except:
            is_fetch_supported = False
    
    return render_template("index.html", is_fetch_supported=is_fetch_supported)

@app.route("/about.html")
def about():
    return render_template('about.html')

@app.route("/contact.html")
def contact():
    return render_template('contact.html')

@app.route('/chat', methods=['POST'])
def chat():
    message = request.form['message']
    response = openai.Completion.create(
        engine="text-davinci-002",
        prompt=message,
        max_tokens=1000,
        n=1,
        stop=None,
        temperature=0.5,
    )
    reply = response.choices[0].text.strip()
    return {'response': reply}

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

I tested the openAi API with streamlit and it worked as expected and I get the response.
Could someone help please ?

Here are the Index.html and Chat.html codes I have used

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <html lang="en">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>AIBot</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='styles.css') }}">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='favicon.ico') }}">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="sidebar">
         <ul>
             <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
             <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
             <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
         </ul>
        </div>
        <h1>Welcome to AI Chat Bot!</h1>
        <p>Enter your message below to start chatting:</p>
        <form id="chat-form">
            <input type="text" id="user-input" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Type your message...">
            <button type="submit" id="send-btn">Send</button>
        </form>
        <div id="chat-box"></div>
    </div>
    {% if is_fetch_supported %}
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    {% else %}
    <!-- Handle unsupported browser case here -->
    {% endif %}
</body>
</html>
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Chat with ChatGPT</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='styles.css') }}">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <h1>Chat with ChatGPT</h1>
    </header>
    <main id="chat-window">
        <div id="message-log"></div>
        <form id="message-form">
            <input type="text" id="message-input" autocomplete="off">
            <button type="submit" id="send-button">Send</button>
        </form>
    </main>
    
    <script src="https://cdn.socket.io/3.0.4/socket.io.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        // Establish a WebSocket connection with the server
        var socket = io.connect('{{ url_for("socketio") }}');

        // Handle incoming bot messages
        socket.on('bot_message', function(message) {
            addBotMessage(message);
        });

        // Send user message to the server
        function sendMessage(message) {
            socket.emit('user_message', message);
            addUserMessage(message);
        }

        // Add a message from the user to the message log
        function addUserMessage(message) {
            var messageLog = document.getElementById('message-log');
            var messageNode = document.createElement('div');
            messageNode.className = 'user-message';
            messageNode.innerHTML = message;
            messageLog.appendChild(messageNode);
        }

        // Add a message from the bot to the message log
        function addBotMessage(message) {
            var messageLog = document.getElementById('message-log');
            var messageNode = document.createElement('div');
            messageNode.className = 'bot-message';
            messageNode.innerHTML = message;
            messageLog.appendChild(messageNode);
        }

        // Handle form submission
        document.getElementById('message-form').addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var inputField = document.getElementById('message-input');
            var message = inputField.value;
            inputField.value = '';
            sendMessage(message);
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm tryed to built a chat bot using opeanAI and I expect to receive an answer to my question when I click on send